# String displayed differently in Toast and Logcat  : Android

Tags: java, android, string

In my application, I want to receive some Strings via bluetooth, and then pass them back to my UI thread using a Handler. I've used a Handler object to pass the data back to main UI thread:

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, length, 0, a).sendToTarget();
```

Notice: **a** is a byte array that I get from Bluetooth InputStream.

In my UI thread, I had:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    byte[] b = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String str = new String(b, 0, msg.arg1);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "mHander: " + str);
                }
}
```

For example, if I send a simple string, "cfm123245", from my other bluetooth device (it's a bluetooth module which is controlled by a micro controller) to my Android phone, the Toast will display exactly "cfm12345" on screen. But in Logcat, I see this ugly string:

```
MainActivity         mHander: cfm��������
```

I don't know why one String object appears differently between Toast and Logcat. And if I get that string to do some further processing methods on it, it seem that I get the ugly `cfm��������` one. So it is wrong data.

Could any one explain to me why this happen? How to fix this? Please help me on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you use the `+` operator I believe `str.toString()` is called behind the scenes. What happens when you use: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it was caused by encoding issue. Try this to see if it helps

```
String str = new String(b, "US-ASCII");
```

You can also try UTF-8 encoding if the above doesnt work.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. I tried both of them before but it did't work.

Answer (score 0):

`mHandler.obtainMessage(FileBrowserActivity.MESSAGE_READ, length, 0, a).sendToTarget();`

I believe `a` in the above **Toast is an Object of some Type**.... And i hope you have overridden its toString() method...

then better go for `a.toString()` or `a + ""` in the **Toast.**